# Find product detail using variant id

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a list of variants in schema with their IDs and the user should be able to choose any of those using drop down box so he can dynamically change the product and its variant inside a DIV. Now, I have been stucked in finding a way to get product title, price and other details using variant Id listed in the schema. I would really appreciate for any kind of suggestion.
Thank you.
[Please check the image for more detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7snaT.png)

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to use this information in a merchant-facing app or the customer-facing storefront?

Assuming the latter (as your screenshot shows the theme/section settings in Shopify), there is no way to get a variant object just from its ID, and even if you could there is no way to easily move from a variant object to a product object in Shopify.

You will need to also collect the associated product handles for the product objects that you want to work with. Once you have a product handle, you can get the product object using Liquid or Javascript quite easily.

Assuming that you have a product handle saved to a variable named `product_handle` and the variant ID saved to a variable named `variant_id`, the code could look something like:

Liquid

```
{% assign product = all_products[product_handle] %}
{% assign variant = product.variants | where: 'id', variant_id | first %}
```

Javascript

```
// Retrieve the product data using Shopify's frontend API endpoint
fetch('/products/' + product_handle + '.js').then(function(response){ return response.json() }).then( 
  function(product){
    let variant = product.variants.find(function(variant){ return variant.id == variant_id })
    // Do stuff with your product & variant objects
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. I really appreciate it. Actually, the interface's users are marketing and communication personnels in the company. I was making a section where a 'Product Bar' will be included and they can add specific variant of product with various infomation related to the blog/article they are creating. Variants ID are in schema as 'select' type and when they choose a variant.id, shopify should display Product title, Variant title, V.image, V.price with V. featured image in that bar. I am quite new in shopify and liquid and have spent many days to solve the problem.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project!  If the product bar will be showing up on the website, you will need the variant ID and the product handle in order to get all of the product information. Hopefully this helps you get there - let me know if you are still stuck.

Comment: Yes, your reply definitely helped me. I had one more thing to ask. As you said above, if it is not possible to get the products info from V.id, is it possible to get info of other variants within the same product from given V.id? I am using type:select in schema to choose the V.id, and tried to put V.id and product_handle as array for value but shopify didn't allow me to do so. Is there any way around to do? So when the user click an option, then it will input two related values. It is just to make it neat and easy and avoid human error that may occure :)

Comment: Yes - once you have a product handle, you can get the product object using `{% assign product = all_products[some_product_handle] %}`, and the product object includes an array of the associated variants as `product.variants`.  Given that, you could iterate through all variants of a product using `{% for variant in product.variants %}` and then do whatever you need to do with them.